# When will ios fire didReceiveMemoryWarning method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, profiling

When will iOS trigger the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method?
I am getting a crash in my app while playing an DRM encryped video.
Check the below screenshot. I am using only 27mb of RAM and I am getting a memory warning in the console as you can see in the image and the app simply crashes. What can be the possible reason?

[image]

I tried profiling the app using allocation instrument. I checked the `discard events with freed memory` and ran the app. There also I am getting the memory warning message even though the app only uses ~50mb of RAM.Please check the image below.

[image]

Comment: IIRC, iOS broadcasts memory warning to all the apps when total free memory is low, so it may be problem caused by other apps.

Comment: But I don't have any other running apps in the background.In the second image attached you can see the  total bytes column.It consumes only 58mb.I checked the `discard events for freed memory` .SO it would be the current amount of RAM used by the app right?

Comment: check `Usage Comparison` in first screenshot.

Comment: Have you try to add a breakpoint to didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get memory warnings with only 7 MB of memory allocated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590063/why-do-i-get-memory-warnings-with-only-7-mb-of-memory-allocated)

Comment: @AhmadF What should I do after putting a breakpoint there?

Comment: @abhi1992 is it reachable? (does the compile stops at it before crashing?)

Comment: @AhmadF yes it is.. I can log some warning message there.